# What If It's Zero?

Tags: arithmetic, systems-of-equations, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

The other day I was deriving the **combined equation for the angle bisectors of a pair of straight lines ($a{x^2} + 2hxy + b{y^2}$) passing through the origin**. After some simplification, I got this equation - $$\left( {{m_1} + {m_2}} \right)\left( {{x^2} - {y^2}} \right) = 2xy\left( {1 - {m_1}{m_2}} \right)$$ 
where ${m_1}$ and ${m_2}$ are the slopes of the straight lines. By substituting ${m_1} + {m_2} = {{ - 2h} \over b}$ and ${m_1}{m_2} = {a \over b}$,$$\left( {{{ - 2h} \over b}} \right)\left( {{x^2} - {y^2}} \right) = 2xy\left( {{{b - a} \over b}} \right)$$
Since $b$ was a constant (coefficient of ${{y^2}}$), I multiplied both sides by $b$ and eliminated it.
But if $b$ happened to be zero, the equation would have been of the form $\infty  = \infty $, and by multiplying $0$ on both sides, the result would be indeterminate.

**How do the proofs tackle the case when denominator can also take the value zero?**

Comment: Proof by cases,you first show what happens if something is zero,then the next case  you assume the value to be non-zero and go on with the proof.

Comment: Once you divide by b you must make a special case before you divide by b to discuss what happens if b = 0.  In this case the equation is ax^2 + 2hxy = x(ax + 2hy) which presumably leads to a different (probably simpler) result.  I'm not entirely sure what you are doing to get m1+m2 = -2h/b (what is h) but that would mean the to slopes add to a vertice slope.  Which is a special case.  probably.

Comment: As I understand it, the two angle bisectors of a pair of intersecting lines are perpendicular to each other and hence the product of  their slopes is $-1$. You have it equal to $a/b$ and if $b=0$ then $a=0$ in which case the equation of the pair is $0=xy$.

Comment: This is the main reason that I avoid using the slope-intercept form of equation of a line when doing analytic geometry: you invariably need special cases for horizontal and vertical lines. Working with the point-normal form almost always eliminates the need for such special cases.

Comment: @fleablood This is the method used to determine ${m_1} + {m_2} =  - 2h/b$ and ${m_1}{m_2} = a/b$. We divide this general equation $a{x^2} + 2hxy + b{y^2}$ by ${x^2}$ and obtain $b{\left( {{y \over x}} \right)^2} + 2h\left( {{y \over x}} \right) + a = 0$. This could be written as $b\left( {{y \over x} - {m_1}} \right)\left( {{y \over x} - {m_2}} \right) = 0$, where ${m_1}$ and ${m_2}$ are the roots (or slopes of straight lines). Comparing it with the original equation, we get the above results. Here, when we divide by ${x^2}$, the special case is $x=0$. I get $y=0$. Doesn't give me the result.

Comment: So you need to take the case if $b=0$ then $ax^2 -2hxy = 0$ so for $x \ne 0$ we have $ax = -2hxy$ which means ... whatever it means.

Comment: argh ax = -2hy...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem came earlier; whatever method you used to determine $m_1 + m_2 = -2h/b$ and $m_1 m_2 = a/b$ is inapplicable in the case that $b=0$.

The usual fix to things like this is to split the problem into two parts:

- Solve the problem under the assumption that $b \neq 0$
- Solve the problem under the assumption that $b = 0$

And then combine the two solutions in whatever manner is appropriate to the problem.

---

As an example of this method, consider the problem of finding under what conditions the equation

$$ a x^2 + bx + c = 0$$

has a unique solution for $x$. We'd be tempted to use the quadratic formula, but that depends on $a$ being nonzero. So we split the problem:

- Assuming $a \neq 0$, we apply the quadratic formula; the solution is unique if and only if $b^2 - 4ac = 0$
- Assuming $a = 0$, we have a linear equation $bx + c = 0$. This has a unique solution if and only if $b \ne 0$

So, the end result is that the equation above has a unique solution for $x$ if and only if one of the following two conditions are satisfied:

- $a \neq 0$ and $b^2 = 4ac$
- $a = 0$ and $b \neq 0$

Comment: In the equation $a{x^2} + bx + c = 0$ that you mentioned above, if I divide both by $a$, then I would have to consider the cases when $a$ is zero and when its not. Do I have to consider similar cases, when I **multiply** both sides by $a$ (if it's zero) ? The equation still remains true though.

Comment: This is the method used to determine $m_1 + m_2 = -2h/b$ and $m_1 m_2 = a/b$. We divide this general equation $a{x^2} + 2hxy + b{y^2}$ by ${x^2}$ and obtain $b{\left( {{y \over x}} \right)^2} + 2h\left( {{y \over x}} \right) + a = 0$. This could be written as $b\left( {{y \over x} - {m_1}} \right)\left( {{y \over x} - {m_2}} \right) = 0$, where ${{m_1}}$ and ${{m_2}}$ are the roots (or slopes of straight lines). Comparing it with the original equation, we get the above results. Here, we divide by ${x^2}$. Do we get the same result if we assume $x$ was zero?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you have to treat those cases separately. [Hurkyl’s answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2270326/265466) covers this quite well. In particular, having to deal with $b=0$ separately comes up much earlier in your calculations.

Sometimes having these special cases is unavoidable, but as I mentioned in my comment to your question, they can often be avoided in problems like this one if you use a different form of equation for the lines, as I’ll illustrate below.

Let the two lines be given by the equations $Ax+By=0$, $Cx+Dy=0$, with $A$, $B$ not both zero and $C$, $D$ not both zero. The combined equation is $$(Ax+By)(Cx+Dy)=AC\,x^2+(AD+BC)\,xy+BD\,y^2=0.$$ Comparing this to your original equation, we must have $$\begin{align} a&=AC \\ b&=BD \\ h&=\frac12(AD+BC).\end{align}$$ The normal vectors to these lines are $\mathbf n_1=(A,B)$ and $\mathbf n_2=(C,D)$ with corresponding direction vectors $\mathbf v_1=(-B,A)$ and $\mathbf v_2=(-D,C)$. The two angle bisectors are then $$\mathbf w_1={\mathbf v_1\over\|\mathbf v_1\|}+{\mathbf v_2\over\|\mathbf v_2\|} \\ \mathbf w_2={\mathbf v_1\over\|\mathbf v_1\|}-{\mathbf v_2\over\|\mathbf v_2\|}.$$ These two vectors are orthogonal, so we can use them for the normals of the two bisecting lines. (It also means that we could’ve used the normals to the original lines directly to find the bisectors.) So, we have for the combined equation of the bisecting lines $(\mathbf w_1\cdot\mathbf x)(\mathbf w_2\cdot\mathbf x)=0$, which after expanding and a bit of fiddling becomes $${AD-BC\over(A^2+B^2)(C^2+D^2)}\left[(AD+BC)(x^2-y^2)-2(AC+BD)\,xy\right]=0.$$ By hypothesis, the denominator is non-zero. Since we have two distinct lines, $ab-h^2\lt0$, which after substitution is $\frac14(BC-AD)^2\gt0$, so in particular $AD-BC\ne0$. The above equation is therefore equivalent to $(AD+BC)(x^2-y^2)-2(AC+BD)\,xy=0$, and substituting the original coefficients into this results in $$h(x^2-y^2)-(a-b)xy=0.$$ As you can see, by starting with the point-normal form of the equations instead of the slope-intercept form, we never had to deal with vertical lines (or any resulting vertical bisectors) separately.